# How to modify the precision of a datetimeoffset column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In a sql-server database with data I have several columns with type `datetimeoffset(7)`. Now I would like to change the precision part of the type to `datetimeoffset(0)`.

Is this possible without creating a new column of the desired type/precision and renaming the column?

I take solutions using SQL Server Management Studio as well as code (or also a no it's not possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be a straightforward

```
alter table tab
alter column x datetimeoffset(0);
```

Comment: This would work - Just remember that you are only saving 2 bytes going from 10 bytes for datetimeoffset(7) to 8 bytes datetimeoffset(0) so altering the table will not save you so much space https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx.

Comment: It works. And it's not about the space but the unneeded precision causes pain at another level.